# PS Passing ParameterSet to switch

Tags: powershell

Hi in this function how can I pass the 'Install' parameter to the $action switch instead of using the default 'Report' ?

```
Function MyFunc()
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Report',
                   PositionalBinding = $true)]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Report',
                   Position = 0)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Install',
                   Position = 0)]
        [switch]$Action
    )

    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
    {
        'Report' {
            Write-Output "Report chosen!" 
            break
        }
        'Install' {
            Write-Output "Install chosen!"
            break
        }
    }
}
```

when I do

MyFunc -Action 'Install'

Throws error:

MyFunc : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Install'.

Thank you.

Comment: I could be wrong because my Powershell is pretty rusty, but shouldn't it be:
Position = 1 for Install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to support one parameter:

```
Function MyFunc()
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Report',
                   PositionalBinding = $true)]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Action',
                   Position = 0)]
        $Action        
    )

    switch ($Action)
    {
        'Report' {
            Write-Output "Report chosen!" 
            break
        }
        'Install' {
            Write-Output "Install chosen!"
            break
        }
    }
}

Get-Help MyFunc
MyFunc -Action 'Install'
```

Executing it:

```
C:\code> powershell.exe .\test.ps1

NAME
    MyFunc

SYNTAX
    MyFunc  [<CommonParameters>]

    MyFunc [[-Action] <Object>]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None

Install chosen!
```